# Making table rows sortable

Tags: jquery, html

How exactly I can make table rows sortable when they are loaded on page via ajax?
I have on the page markup where I load the table via ajax

```
<div id="mycart" style="text-align:center;"> </div>
```

This is the script with which I trying to sort tr's on the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
   var $originals = tr.children();
   var $helper = tr.clone();
   $helper.children().each(function(index) {
       $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
   });
   return $helper;
},
updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
    $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
    });
};

$("#sort tbody").sortable({
   helper: fixHelperModified,
   stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
});
```

When I put `$("#mycart tbody").sortable({` it is working but is moving whole mycart div. So how can I select table which isn't "really" on the page... in source of the page I see only `<div id="mycart" style="text-align:center;"> </div>`.. I don't see actual table.
Here is the js whit which I pull data

```
function show_cart()
{
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'includes/store_items.php',
  data:{
    showcart:"cart"
  },
  success:function(response) {
    document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;

    $("#mycart").slideToggle();
  }
 });
```

Comment: Does it have to use <table> or will a div grid layout suffice in this use case? Table is going to get much harder since you cant move the rows - you can only move the content in the rows. So with a table, you will have to manipulate the data. With a div grid, you can sort the div's containing the data. Seems like a subtle difference, but the implications on the amount of code you will have to write is more significant. I see your example code references the table elements - but was using tables for this a decision on your end or are you constrained by the architecture?

Comment: Table just  fit better on whole vision and architecture of the site. Isn't that mandatory but is preferable to be table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to call the same [JQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) function in your ajax request's success callback, right after putting the new HTML:

```
 success:function(response) {   

     document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
     // or $("#mycart").html(response);

     $("#sort tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelperModified,
        stop: updateIndex
     }).disableSelection();

     $("#mycart").slideToggle();

}
```

**Update:** And you may need to move the following functions outside the `$(document).ready({});`:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
   var $originals = tr.children();
   var $helper = tr.clone();
   $helper.children().each(function(index) {
       $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
   });
   return $helper;
},
updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
    $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
        $(this).html(i + 1);
    });
};
```

Comment: I've got `Uncaught ReferenceError: fixHelperModified is not defined` when I try to slideout (`$("#mycart").slideToggle();`) the table.

Comment: Okay, now the `tr` are getting moved but doesn't actually move. I mean I drag the tr to another tr place but is back on the original place.

Comment: Well .. still same. I can move around tr but doesn't go on new place .. just goes back to his place

Comment: By the way I put the js part in success function right?

Comment: Anyway I will accept your answer it was helpful and I will figured it out why doesn't want to stay on the new place.

Comment: Glad that it helped you somehow. It seems like now you have an issue with your `sortable` function's properties according to the situation. You can post an other question with complete current code.